# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function tab() on null

Tags: php, pdo

Простая ошибка, но не могу понять что не так.

config.php

```
<?php
class Database {
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $db_name = 'agency';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = 'root';
    public $conn;

public function getConnection(){
    $this->conn = null;
    try{
        $this->conn=new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->db_name,$this->username, $this->password);
    } catch(PDOException $exception){
        echo "Ошибка соединения".$exception->getMessage();
    }
    return $this->conn;
}
}
?>
```

function.php

```
<?php
class About_us{
public function __construct($db){
    $this->conn = $db;
}
function tab(){
     $query = "SELECT * FROM about_us";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
                }
}     
?>
```

about_us.php

```
<?php
require_once "config.php"; 
require_once "functions.php";
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$ab = new About_us($db);

$stmt=$product->tab();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);
    echo "{$description}";
}
?>
```

Из БД agency нужно вывести значение description из таблицы about_us.

Comment: Включите отображение ошибок уровня E_NOTICE, посмотрите на сообщение о неизвестной переменной `$product`, посмотрите на код и сможете ответить

Comment: Спасибо, в одном месте название переменной поменяла, а про другое забыла